# Dynamic header menus common for all pages in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I want to make a dynamic menu and this dynamic menu is common for all pages of my website. This thing i have done in php but i have to achieve the same using codeigniter. So, what to do show all menus on all pages.

I have done this thing on controller.

```
    if(!isset($courses['code'])){
        $data['courses'] = $courses;
    }


    $this->load->view('common/'.$page, $data);
```

where $page=header.

THIS FUNCTION IS IN MY COURSE MODEL.

public function fetchCourses()
    {

```
    $this->db->select('id, course_name, image, sort_order, parent_id, date_added, status');
    $this->db->from('ls_courses');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if(!empty($query->result_array()))
    {
        return $query->result_array();
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->db->error();
    }
}
```

AND THIS IS MY VIEW UL.

```
            <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo base_url(''); ?>">Home</a></li>

            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('about'); ?>">About Us</a></li>

            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('courses'); ?>">Courses<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>

              <ul class="dropdown_menu">

                <?php if(isset($courses) && !empty($courses)) { ?>
                <?php foreach ($courses as $key => $value) {?>

                <li><a href=""><?php echo $value['course_name']; ?></a>
                  <?php } ?>
                  <?php } ?>
```

```
       <?php if(isset($childcourses) && !empty($childcourses)) {  ?>
                 <?php foreach ($childcourses as $key => $value) { ?>
                                            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('course/details/'.$value['seo_url']); ?>"><?php echo $value['course_name']; ?></a></li>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

there are so many helper available for template layout  ... or simply ... add one more method in all your controllers ...

```
function template($page_name,$data,$headrdata,$footerdata)
{
 $this->load->view('header',$headrdata);
$this->load->view($page_name,$data);
$this->load->view('footer',$footerdata);
}
```

and load view like

```
if(!isset($courses['code'])){
    $data['courses'] = $courses;
}
$this->template('view_name',$data,$headrdata,footerdata);
```